# I can't import a .js file on a .html document

Tags: javascript, html, file, server

I have a little trouble: on a server I published a .js file where I declared a function that simplifies the `document.write()` function:

```
function print(id, text){document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;}
```

> I already tested this code calling the function `print("paragraph", "Hello, world!");` and it works, but I don't know why when I created a new .html file and imported the **easyjs_demo.js** file and in the `<script>` tag I called the `print` function, it didn't work:

```
<body>
      <p id="paragraph"></p>
      <script src="easyjs_demo.js">
      print("paragraph", "Hello, world!");
      </script>
</body>
```

Do you know how can I import the **.js** file wothout having bugs like this? Thank You very much!

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: you're importing the easyjs_demo.js before calling your print function?

Comment: Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509323/script-tags-with-src-and-code-between-script-tags

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh the page prints nothing

Answer (score 5):

You can't combine includes and code, try separating Your external file, and the inline code like this:

```
<script src="easyjs_demo.js"></script>
<script>
  print("paragraph", "Hello, world!");
</script>
```

Demo Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mXu3AMxA69Uz2DbTT1tK?p=preview).

---

Multiple sources show that if You specify the `src` attribute, the user agent ignores the inline code:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html
- [JavaScript: Inline Script with SRC Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute)
- [What if script tag has both "src" and inline script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540581/what-if-script-tag-has-both-src-and-inline-script)

Comment: glad i could help, if you don't have any further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)