# Javascript button not displaying quotes as should

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and I followed a tutorial to create a random quote generator: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/creating-a-bare-bones-quote-generator-with-javascript-and-html-for-absolute-beginners-5264e1725f08

However, my New Quote button doesn't display quotes when you click the button. Nothing happens.

I think the problem is that I'm not correctly referencing to the javascript.js file which has the array of quotes. index.html and javascript.js are in the same level in one folder, and I moved the javascript function newQuote() to my HTML file for simplicity.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Funny Quote Gen</title>

    <script src="javascript.js">
        function newQuote() {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length()));
            document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Simple Funny Quote Generator</h1>

    <div id="quoteDisplay">
        <!-- Quotes will display here! -->
    </div>

    <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
</body>
</html>
```

javascipt.js:

```
var quotes [
    'Do not take life too seriously. You will never get out of \it alive. - Elbert Hubbard',
    'May the forces of evil become confused on the way to your house. - George Carlin',
    'Laziness \is nothing more than the habit of resting before you get tired. - Jules Renard', 
    'There can not be a crisis next week. My schedule \is already full. - Henry Kissinger',
    'My life needs editing. - Mort Sahl',
    'I always wanted to be somebody, but now \I realize \I should have been more specific. - Lily Tomin',
    'If at first you don\'t succeed, find out \if the loser gets anything. - William Lyon Phelps',
    'You\'re only as good as your last haircut. - Fran Lebowitz'
]
```

Comment: You can't put JS code within the same `<script>` tag as an imported file. Try `<script src="javascript.js"></script> <script> *Code here* </script>` instead.

Comment: You can’t use `src` and script content in the same `<script>` tag. Other than that, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. `quotes.length` isn’t a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script tags with src and code between script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509323/script-tags-with-src-and-code-between-script-tags)

Comment: put your quotes array also on index.html without referencing from another javascript.js file

Comment: I think length is a property on Array. So instead of quotes.length() update it to quotes.length. make sure you follow the above comments also.

Comment: Also, you’re missing a `=` after `var quotes`.

Comment: @Xufox Didn't know the existence of that functionality, thanks very much. Will use from now on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here - first you'll want to change your HTML as follows:

```
<!-- Separate the loading of the javascript.js script -->
<script src="javascript.js"></script> 

<!-- Ensure this script block is declared second -->
<script>

    function newQuote() {
        // .length is a property, not a function, of an array - replace 
        // length() with .length. Access the quotes via window.quotes
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.quotes.length));

        // Again, access the quotes via window.quotes
        document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = window.quotes[randomNumber];
    }
</script>
```

In your javascript.js file, attach the quotes to the current window as follows:

```
window.quotes = [
    'Do not take life too seriously. You will never get out of \it alive. - Elbert Hubbard',
    'May the forces of evil become confused on the way to your house. - George Carlin',
    'Laziness \is nothing more than the habit of resting before you get tired. - Jules Renard', 
    'There can not be a crisis next week. My schedule \is already full. - Henry Kissinger',
    'My life needs editing. - Mort Sahl',
    'I always wanted to be somebody, but now \I realize \I should have been more specific. - Lily Tomin',
    'If at first you don\'t succeed, find out \if the loser gets anything. - William Lyon Phelps',
    'You\'re only as good as your last haircut. - Fran Lebowitz'
]
```

The use of `window` in this way allows the `quotes` variable that you're declaring in the javascript.js file to be accessed from another script/file (ie the script block in your HTML file).

The `window` object is a single "global" object that is accessible from any javascript file run in the browser. We can "tack" variables/data/objects onto the `window` object, when we need to share access of those things between files/script blocks - as in the case of your project.

You should find these fixes get your project running - if you'd like to see it in action, [here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0nkm25e/2/)

Comment: Why is the assignment to a `window` property needed here?

Comment: Thank you, the separation of loading script with other script solved my issue (amongst other typos). But I also do not understand what "windows" does

Comment: @JessicaWang It’s not needed at all in this case. Assigning to a `window` property makes a variable globally accessible, but that’s already the case for `var quotes`. `window.quotes` is bad practice since it pollutes the global namespace and may clash with existing properties. Don’t use it.

Answer (score 3):

You've 2 possible solution to fix that.

1. Reference your `javascript.js` file on another script tag like as per your existing tutorial. See the last line before closing body tag e.g `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`.

[image]

**OR**

- Push all your javascript code under one single script tag like- but first of all fix some of your existing errors-

  - Remove parenthesis `()` from length property as it is not a function.
  - Fix `quotes` array like `var quotes = [your long array values will goes here]` etc. You're missging `=` here

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Funny Quote Gen</title>
  <script>
    var quotes = [
      'Do not take life too seriously. You will never get out of \it alive. - Elbert Hubbard',
      'May the forces of evil become confused on the way to your house. - George Carlin',
      'Laziness \is nothing more than the habit of resting before you get tired. - Jules Renard',
      'There can not be a crisis next week. My schedule \is already full. - Henry Kissinger',
      'My life needs editing. - Mort Sahl',
      'I always wanted to be somebody, but now \I realize \I should have been more specific. - Lily Tomin',
      'If at first you don\'t succeed, find out \if the loser gets anything. - William Lyon Phelps',
      'You\'re only as good as your last haircut. - Fran Lebowitz'
    ];


    function newQuote() {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
      document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simple Funny Quote Generator</h1>

  <div id="quoteDisplay">
    <!-- Quotes will display here! -->
  </div>

  <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script tag is improperly used. You can not import external js file and put code inside script tag at the same time . Only one thing can happen at a time.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Funny Quote Gen  </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Simple Funny Quote  Generator</h1>

<div id="quoteDisplay">
    <!-- Quotes will display here! -->
</div>

<button  onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</ button>
</body>



<script>
    function newQuote() {
var quotes = [
'Do not take life too seriously. You   will never get out    of \it alive. - Elbert Hubbard',
   'May the forces of evil become   confused on the way to your house. - George Carlin',
   'Laziness \is nothing more than the habit of resting before you get tired. - Jules Renard', 
   'There can not be a crisis next week. My schedule \is already full. - Henry Kissinger',
    'My life needs editing. - Mort Sahl',
    'I always wanted to be somebody, but now \I realize \I should have been more specific. - Lily Tomin',
    'If at first you don\'t succeed, find out \if the loser gets anything. - William Lyon Phelps',
    'You\'re only as good as your last haircut. - Fran Lebowitz'
 ];
        var randomNumber =    Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length()));
        document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: These issues still remain: the HTML is invalid, the JS is invalid, `length` still isn’t a function.

Comment: Updated @Xufox Please let me know any more